# Where are the cast and crew logos in Game of Thrones opening credits from?

Tags: game-of-thrones, symbols

For the Game of Thrones crew, what do the symbols next to their names mean? For example, Ramin Djawadi, Gemma Jackson, and GRRM have a symbol that looks like an NES controller d-pad, editor Martin Nicholson has two crossed swords and a star, producer Mark Huffam has what appears to be a four-pointed flower, producer Frank Doelger has four small stars, etc...

A few examples :

[image: Nathalie Dormer]
[image: Kit Harington]
[image: George R. R. Martin]

Comment: This Question is not exactly about the Content of GoT or ASOIAF which is foundation of that content. So I don't think it has any place here. May be Movies and TV exchange would serve you better?

Comment: If had been about sigils shown next to names of the cast, then we could have answered it. But it is about names of people who are not playing any character so it is not about science fiction or fantasy

Comment: I think it is fine, it is a question about the series and while I think they might get a better answer on the Tv and Movies stackexchange this question does not, not belong here. @Aegon

Comment: This question is totally fine here. We've had successful behind-the-scenes questions before. In fact: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2944/what-type-of-behind-the-scenes-questions-are-on-topic

Comment: the one GRRM has chosen as a sigil is a Turtle (cuz he loves em and has pet turtles as well), sourced from an interview.. others m not aware / could'nt find.

Comment: @Aegon Mooz is correct. It's true this question would be on-topic at M&TV (and I'll migrate if if *the OP* asks), but it's *also* on-topic here ("behind-the-scenes and fandom information" as [explicitly mentioned in the help centre](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)), so it shouldn't be closed and doesn't have to be migrated.

Comment: Similar question from sister site: [Do the sigils next to the names of staff in the Game of Thrones intro all exist in the fictional world?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/70723/do-the-sigils-next-to-the-names-of-staff-in-the-game-of-thrones-intro-all-exist)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## It Is Known

**George R. R. Martin**

The [answer by @RicoRicochet](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/129097/58193) gives the reasoning for his in that it is a turtle because ["Turtles have always been my sigil, I suppose."](http://www.makinggameofthrones.com/production-diary/2012/7/14/seven-moments-from-the-game-of-thrones-comic-con-panel-that.html).

[image: George R. R. Martin]

**Bryan Cogman**

This is allegedly a vomiting maester after Bryan had a bit too much too drink at a wrap party though I'm not sure how true the claim is.

> Look closely next to writer Bryan Cogman’s name in the opening credits and you’ll see his ‘House Sigil’ is a vomiting maester. This joke was made by Benioff and Weiss in reference to a wrap party at which he er, overindulged himself, back when he worked as their assistant.
>   <sub>[Den of Geek!, 67 Things You Didn't Know About Game of Thrones Season 4](http://www.denofgeek.com/us/tv/game-of-thrones/243771/67-things-you-didnt-know-about-game-of-thrones-season-4)</sub>

[image: Bryan Cogman]

**Ramin Djawadi**

George's turtle.

[image: Ramin Djawadi]

**Gemma Jackson**

George's turtle.

[image: Gemma Jackson]

**Guymon Casady**

George's turtle.

[image: Guymon Casady]

**Deborah Riley**

George's turtle.

[image: Deborah Riley]

**Carolyn Strauss**

An ostrich is Strauss in German.

[image: Carolyn Strauss]

## It Is Not Known

I've seen it noted that the crew got to choose their own sigils for the credits but I haven't actually been able to track down a reliable source for the claim yet though it sounds plausible.

**Nina Gold, Robert Sterne**

Fleur-de-lis not sure why.

[image: Nina Gold, Robert Sterne]

**Michele Clapton**

Some sort of bird posturing.

[image: Michele Clapton]

**Frances Parker A.C.E**

I can't really make it out but some sort of cat or a helm looking left.

[image: Frances Parker A.C.E]

**Kramer Morgenthau A.S.C**

What looks to be a hammer.

[image: Kramer Morgenthau A.S.C]

**Vince Gerardis**

Some sort of flower.

[image: Vince Gerardis]

**Alan Taylor**

The same as Kramer.

[image: Alan Taylor]

**Vanessa Taylor**

Appears to be a bird or fish.

[image: Vanessa Taylor]

**Bernadette Caulfield**

Triangular symbol, hut?

[image: Bernadette Caulfield]

**Frank Doelger**

Four stars in a cross.

[image: Frank Doelger]

**David Benioff, D.B. Weiss**

Appropriately two skulls.

[image: David Benioff, D.B. Weiss]

**Joe Bauer**

A crab.

[image: Joe Bauer]

**Steve Kullback**

A man holding up the moon?

[image: Steve Kullback]

**Crispin Green**

Two crossed swords.

[image: Crispin Green]

**Gregory Middleton A.S.C C.S.C**

The same as Frances Parker A.C.E.

[image: Gregory Middleton A.S.C C.S.C]

**Lisa McAtackney, Greg Spence**

Lisa's is a quill and Greg's is a flying bird.

[image: Lisa McAtackney, Greg Spence]

**Chris Newman**

Some circular pattern.

[image: Chris Newman]

Comment: Thanks for adding all the others. I understand GRRM is fond of turtles, but if that symbol is a turtle, then I clearly don't know what turtles look like. Also Steve Kullback appears to be Sisyphus; Crispin Green crossed swords kinda look like scissors (for editing film); Frank Doelger perhaps sees himself as a 4-star general; Michelle Clapton a peacock for the beautiful costume design.

Comment: @TheMiddler Yeah I'd worked some of the hidden meanings out, like the swords, but I didn't want to add it in until I knew for sure that was the case

Comment: Nice answer, maybe you wish to [repost it here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/70723/do-the-sigils-next-to-the-names-of-staff-in-the-game-of-thrones-intro-all-exist/70887#70887) , I have  my own answer there but this one is more detailed

Comment: Michele Clapton's sigil look like peacock to me

Comment: @TheMiddler maybe GRRM is fond of the Playstation Dualshock™ directional buttons.

Answer (score 16):

The sigil of George R. R. Martin which seems to look like a "NES controller d-pad" is in reality a **turtle**.

The sigils of the cast members are their character's house, e.g. a Lannister lion for Peter Dinklage, a three-headed dragon for Emilia Clarke. A similar concept is used for crew as well. In this case, it is a personal choice. The most notable example being the one of G.R.R. Martin himself.

As mentioned by G.R.R.M in [San Diego Comic-Con 2012](http://www.makinggameofthrones.com/production-diary/2012/7/14/seven-moments-from-the-game-of-thrones-comic-con-panel-that.html) -

> Turtles have always been my sigil, I suppose. When I was a kid,
>   growing up in Bayonne, NJ, I lived in a federal housing project, and
>   we were not allowed to have a dog or cats. The only pets I could have
>   were turtles. So, I had an entire toy castle filled with dime-store
>   turtles. I gave them all names, and since they were living in a toy
>   castle, I decided they were all knights and kings...and I made up
>   stories about how they killed each other and betrayed each other and
>   fought for the kingdom. So, Game of Thrones, actually began with
>   turtles. I decided later to recast it with actual human beings.

As for others, it can take a while to research. From the analysis of G.R.R.M. himself, we can assume the sigils to be just a personal choice.

Comment: So... Game of Thrones is just "[turtles all the way down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down)"?

Comment: aye, sea-turtles mate :D

Comment: They like to have fun with the sigils. [Bryan Cogman](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Bryan_Cogman) is a prime example: "The sigil next to Cogman's name in the opening credits is actually a vomiting maester - a joke by Benioff and Weiss, referencing how at the Season 1 wrap party, Cogman had too much to drink and had to throw up."

Comment: @Madgarr -  Wow, that is a nice reference, I'll try to find out more over the weekend and update the answer.